# Get the max value of 2nd column where the value in column 1 = specified, from dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame. eg:

```
df=
  paper id  year
0         3  1997
1         3  1999
2         3  1999
3         3  1999
4         6  1997
                so on
```

I want the maximum year corresponding to a paper id given as input. For example, if the paper id given is `3`, I want `1999` as the answer.

How can I do this?

Comment: @jezrael I want a Scalar output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 general solutions - filter first and then get `max`:

```
s = df.loc[df['paper id'] == 3, 'year'].max()
print (s)
1999
```

---

```
s = df.set_index('paper id').loc[3, 'year'].max()
print (s)
1999
```

Or aggregate `max` to `Series` and then select by `index` values:

```
s = df.groupby('paper id')['year'].max()
print (s)
paper id
3    1999
6    1997
Name: year, dtype: int64

print (s[3])
1999
```